# How to use laravel decrement methods in a one to many relationship particularly to a specific column

Tags: laravel

I have two tables warrants and expenditures as follows

1. warrants table

   ```
     <?php

   use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
   use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

   class CreateWarrantsTable extends Migration
   {
       /**
        * Run the migrations.
        *
        * @return void
        */
       public function up()
       {
           Schema::create('warrants', function (Blueprint $table) {
               $table->id();
               $table->string('allocation');
               $table->double('originalWarrant',8,2);
               $table->string('description');
               $table->string('awno');
               $table->date('warrant_date') ;
               $table->string('donor_code') ;
               $table->string('donor_name');
               $table->string('ministry') ;
               $table->softdeletes();
               $table->timestamps();
           });
      }

         /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
        Schema::dropIfExists('warrants');
        }
    }
   ```
2. expenditures table

   ```
   <?php

   use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
   use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

   class CreateExpendituresTable extends Migration
   {
       /**
       * Run the migrations.
       *
       * @return void
       */
       public function up()
       {
           Schema::create('expenditures', function (Blueprint $table) {
               $table->id();
               $table->date('expdate');
               $table->string('supliers');
               $table->string('details');
               $table->string('pvno')->nullable();
               $table->string('lpono')->nullable();
               $table->string('invoice_no')->nullable();
               $table->string('dwno')->nullable();
               $table->integer('warrant_id') ;
               $table->double('actual_exp',8,2);
               $table->softdeletes();
               $table->timestamps();
            });
      }

       /**
        * Reverse the migrations.
        *
        * @return void
        */
       public function down()
       {
           Schema::dropIfExists('expenditures');
       }
   }
   ```

I have been trying to decrement a column called originalWarrant (i.e. the amount warranted) in the warrants table from expenditures table. Below is my store method in my ExpenditureController

```
 public function store(CreateExpenditureRequest $request)
     {
         // $input = $request->all()

         $expenditure = $this->expenditureRepository->create(
             [
                 'expdate' => $request->expdate,
                 'supliers' => $request->supliers,
                 'details' => $request->details,
                 'pvno' => $request->pvno,
                 'lpono' => $request->lpono,
                 'invoice_no' => $request->invoice_no,
                 'dwno' => $request->dwno,
                 'warrant_id' => $request->warrant_id,
                 'actual_exp' => $request->actual_exp,
                 'output' => $request->output]
         );

         $warrant = $this->warrantRepository->decreaseAllocationAmount('originalWarrant',$request->actual_exp);

         Flash::success('Expenditure saved successfully.');

         return redirect(route('trackexpenses.expenditures.index'));
     }
```

I put my decreaseAllocationAmount() in my WarrantRepository as below

```
  <?php

 namespace App\Repositories\Trackexpenses;

 use App\Models\Trackexpenses\Warrant;
 use App\Repositories\BaseRepository;

 /**
  * Class WarrantRepository
  * @package App\Repositories\Trackexpenses
  * @version December 18, 2020, 4:12 am UTC
  */

 class WarrantRepository extends BaseRepository
 {

      /**
      * Configure the Model
      **/
      public function model()
     {
         return Warrant::class;
     }


     public function decreaseAllocationAmount($columnname = 'originalWarrant', $actual_exp)
      {
         return $this->model->query()
          ->orderBy($columnname)
         ->decrement($columnname, $actual_exp);
     }
 }
```

With my decreaseAllocationAmount() methods above is able to decrement originalWarrant given the actual_exp, however all orinalWarrant amount are decremented. How to decrement  a particular originalWarrant column with a given $actual_exp specific for the originalWarrant?

Comment: you would need to add a `where` condition to filter the query to only the record you want to decrement

Comment: would you like to show examples

Comment: how do you know what record you want to update? how are you identifying that record?

Comment: I know from the warrant_id

Comment: i would guess that on warrent the field is 'id'   .... `where('id', $warrant_id)`

Comment: could you please complete it I'm having trouble with it

Comment: explain what ... do you know how to do this with SQL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226795/discussion-between-kairaoi-t-and-lagbox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you to not decrement all rows of Warrants, you should make conditional `SQL` logic based on the model.

```
 public function decreaseAllocationAmount(Expenditure $expenditure, $columnname = 'originalWarrant', $actual_exp)
 {
     return $this->model->query()
         ->where('id', $expenditure->warrant_id)
         ->orderBy($columnname)
         ->decrement($columnname, $actual_exp);
 }
```

When you call it, you need to pass the `$expenditure`.

```
$warrant = $this->warrantRepository->decreaseAllocationAmount($expenditure, 'originalWarrant',$request->actual_exp);
```

Comment: there is Undefined variable: expenditure

Comment: You need to change the parameters of the function to Expenditure $expenditure, $columnname = 'originalWarrant', $actual_exp as shown in the code block